# capture video resolution from device

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to let user select only videos that meet certain resolution requirements. And it is not working for me.

For example if I wanted to show only videos that were vertical then it does not work on iOS or most Android devices because thumbnail images all have same dimensions.

Any ideas on this will be greatly appreciated.
Below is the code I am using that does not work:

```
getPhotos = () => { 
    var { photos } = this.state;
    CameraRoll.getPhotos({ first: 100, assetType: "Videos" })
    .then(r => {
        r.edges.map(val => {
            if ( val.node.image.playableDuration < 301 && val.node.image.width <= 1920 && val.node.image.height <= 1080 ) {
                photos.push(val);
                this.setState({ photos });
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: here is the code I am using that does not work:getPhotos = () => {
    var { photos } = this.state;
    CameraRoll.getPhotos({
      first: 100,
      assetType: "Videos"
    }).then(r => {
      r.edges.map(val => {
        if (
          val.node.image.playableDuration < 301 &&
          val.node.image.width <= 1920 &&
          val.node.image.height <= 1080
        ) {
          photos.push(val);
          this.setState({
            photos
          });
        }
      });
    });
  };